# How to select ID by name in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say I have:

```
<div id='test1'></div>
```

I want to refer to it simply as:

```
test1
```

in code. instead of:

```
document.getElementById('test1');
$('#test1') // if in jquery
```

And I don't want to do **`window.test1 = $('#test1');`** I'm looking for a general solution. I know I could probably iterate through all id's with a function on init, but what if dom elements are created dynamically throughout the program. I don't want to run that function that assigns ids to the window every time I add a dom element.

I want `test1` **(and all id's on the page)** to ALWAYS be part of the window object. by default. Is there a way to do this? Like maybe there's a way to inject code when someone tries to access a window object that doesn't exist, and somehow that code will do a **`document.getElementById`** without me having to write it explicitly.

Comment: I hate typing verbose code, so I'll store things in short variables. `var t1 = $('#test1')[0]` for a plain JavaScript object.

Comment: what if I had many id's on the page, or id's that get added to the page dynamically.. thats too much work

Comment: Welcome to JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Proxy` which translates property accesses to dom lookups.

```
const dom = new Proxy(window, {
    get(_, name) {
        return document.getElementById(name);
    }
});

dom.test1.style.position = "static"; // tada
```

Note: don't actually do this

Answer (score 1):

First, your question related to the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), not Javascript. And second, no, as the current standards, there are no ways to achieve that. Of course, you can assign the selector to a variable and re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

So *technically* your IDs are actually already exposed as global variables (at least in Chrome).  Open the console and try typing out one of your IDs.  However, relying on this is a *very bad idea*.

Consider the scenario where you've got an element called `window`.  Well, that's not going to be exposed as a global, as it'd conflict with the global `window` object.

There are good reasons for being explicit when accessing the DOM, and the cognitive burden you introduce by attempting to make this more convenient will undoubtably bite you later down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a window variable in jQuery as:-

```
function (elem) {
    window['id_' + elem.attr('id')] = elem;
}

elem($("#test1"));
```

Create a general function to add a window variable everytime a dynamic element is created. But you need to somehow call the function where dynamic variable gets created.